# Firebase related pods are automatically added in the project pod file, which I haven't specified in pod file

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I have the following pods listed in my podfile

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', git: 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git', branch: '3_0_0'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

But after I installed the above pods using "pod install", I have some additional pods installed in my project as follows,

```
FirebaseAnalytics
FirebaseCore
FirebaseInstanceID
```

likewise, May I know why this happens,
If in case its some sort of dependencies related, please let me know along which pod these dependencies are installed.

Comment: Beca sue `pod Google/SignIn` will have at some a dependency on `pod Google`, which has declared `"dependencies": {"FirebaseAnalytics": ["~> 3.2"]}` (source: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/8/b/3/Google/3.0.3/Google.podspec.json)

Comment: @Larme: Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Recently `Firebase` linked up with `Google`.

So Google make some framework mandatory, if you have use any product of google then Below framework is mandatory (If use Pods)

```
FirebaseAnalytics
FirebaseCore
```

There is no official docs available from google.

I had said above statement by my personal experience. I have use Google/SignIn and firebase in many Projects of google by using Cocoa Pods, My conclusion is that Above framework mandatory for any specially for `Google/SignIn` it is mandatory.

Comment: Could you please share any official link stated by Google regarding this mandatory framework  inclusion ?